# How to get count of model elements using linq

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, enums

I am working on .NET Core. I have nested models which displays data in row wise.

```
public class States
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<DateData> States { get; set; }
}

public class DateData
{
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
  public StateType type { get; set; }
}

public enum StateType 
{
  Available,
  NotAvailable
}
```

Where StateType is enum.

Here, States contains state type and each date which displays row wise.

I need to filter my response based on enum to get total count of NotAvailable date.

Note: I need to get data based on date. Like, all data of 09/10/2020 with StateType.NotAvailable. List States contains multiple data for same date.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Assuming `s` is an object of type `States`, then maybe `s.States.Where(st => st.StateType == StateType.NotAvailable).Count`? (untested)

Comment: @ADyson I have tried this, but it is returning whole model, got nothing filtered.

Comment: "but it is returning whole model, got nothing filtered. " are you sure that you have `Available` present in the collection?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh I disagree - demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HkEORr . You must have miscalculated. I have formalised this with an answer below - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64754125/5947043, please take a look.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly you want from the States object a count of all from it's list of States that are not available

```
var stateObject= new States()

var count = stateObject.States.Count(x => x.type == StateType.NotAvailable);
```

Answer (score 3):

For a single `States` object

```cs
obj.States.Where(x => x.type == StateType.NotAvailable).Count()
```

For a list of `States` objects

```cs
objs.SelectMany(x => x.States).Where(x => x.type == StateType.NotAvailable).Count()
```

Comment: Second answer words for me but I need to get data based on date. Like, all data of 09/10/2020 with StateType.NotAvailable

Comment: You could extend the where clause like (x => x.type == StateType.NotAvailable && x.Date == DateTime.Parse("09/10/2020"))

Comment: @AbhishekSingh " but I need to get data based on date. Like, all data of 09/10/2020 with StateType.NotAvailable" why didn't you mention this in your original post? it sounds very important. Is this the last requirement change? or will you dig out a third one, after the people here adapt their solution and solve your second problem?

Comment: @MongZhu my apologies sir, Can you please help to solve this?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh senz solved it already, see the comment

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Take a look at my second comment

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the list using a Linq `Where` function, and then use `Count()` to total the number of items remaining afterwards.

e.g. if `s` is an instance of `States`, then:

```
var count = s.StateList.Where(st => st.type == StateType.NotAvailable).Count();
```

or alternatively:

```
var count = s.StateList.Count(st => st.type == StateType.NotAvailable);
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IiNpue

N.B. I renamed `States.States` to `States.StateList` because (in .NET Core 3.1 at least) a property cannot have the same name as its enclosing type.